# MS Access 2013 SQL wildcarding, regex-like syntax

Tags: sql, regex, ms-access-2013

The link below seems to indicate that "[a-zA-Z]*" should only match on zero or more alphabetic characters.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff192499.aspx

However, in testing it seems to return results that I don't expect; for example, that contain spaces.

```
Select * from table1 where name like 'r[a-zA-Z]* e[a-zA-Z]*'
```

Should only return consecutive words in the name field where the first word starts with r and none or more alphabetic chars separated by a space and a second word that starts with e.

But executing this statement returns the following (some examples from the result set)

- Red Elder (correct)
- Red Myzomela eruthrina (incorrect)

Is there a way to get the search to return exactly what I expect? What am I not understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a regular expression. The `*` does not apply to the `[a-zA-Z]`.

`r[a-zA-Z]* e[a-zA-Z]*` is interpreted as:

- `r`
- followed by any character a to z
- followed by zero or more characters
- followed by a space
- followed by `e`
- followed by any character a to z
- followed by zero or more characters

Unfortunately you have to use something like this:

`Select * from table1 where name like "r*" and mid(name , instr(name , " ") + 1, 1) = "e"`

which isn't pretty and isn't precisely what you want.